# Page cut off animation in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

I'm trying to achieve animation like below image within view-pager, I googled and got [PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer) but yet its not same as I want even tried to modify the code of pageTransformer but no luck, any other way to achieve below effect within view-pager?

[image]

**Code**

```
    public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
                // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
                view.setAlpha(1);
                view.setTranslationX(0);
                view.setScaleX(1);
                view.setScaleY(1);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
                // Fade the page out.
                view.setAlpha(1 - position);

                // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

                // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
                float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                        + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
//              view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
//              view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want the page to be visible "behind" the shown page? I think I don't understand what you want to do exactly, because you could achieve that by just removing the `setAlpha(1-position)' and `setAlpha(0)` (without the shadow)

Comment: @super-qua same effect as in above image while swiping a page.